# Complexity of calculating Takagi's factorization of $n \times n$ matrix

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

As described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition#Takagi%27s_factorization) the Takagi factorization of a square symmetric complex matrix $A=VDV^T$  where D is a real nonnegative diagonal matrix, and V is unitary. I'm wondering what the complexity of calculating this is for a $n\times n$ matrix? I would think $O(n^{2.8074})$, if using Strassen's matrix multiplication algorithm, as the decomposition involves finding the eigenvalues of a matrix but I'm not sure.

Comment: The complexity of matrix multiplication is not $O(n^{2.8074})$. It is in fact currently unknown.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The complexity of Strassen's matrix multiplication algorithm is O(n^2.807) I'm not sure I understand the difference.

Comment: Right. And this is not the complexity of matrix multiplication.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see, so does this mean the time complexity of calculating the Takagi factorization is unknown as well?

Comment: I assume so. Any evaluation based on the complexity of matrix multiplication will inherit this uncertainty ($\Omega(n^2)$ is obvious but $\Omega(n^{2+\epsilon})$ is not). There could be alternative methods for evaluation but I would expect a similar uncertainty anyway.